# Network drive and open with?

Tags: windows-xp

I have a problem on A windows xp sp3 in my active directory domain. 
I have this problem with only  1 pc. 
When I click on a network drive, the window " to open with " appears. 
Nevertheless I found no Autorun and there is McAfee up to date. 
For information if I reach has the same sharing by (to start - > to execute) it is OK

Thank you in advance for your help
yza

Answer (score 0):

That "open a file with" stuff is based on the associations in the registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  I know if you whack the .exe you'll get that message.  (Easy way to ruin an unattended machine in 30 seconds or less.)

Doing some digging, you might want to export the registry keys from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive from a working xp machine (#1), then import those into the nonworking machine (#2) by clicking on that resulting .reg file you get from machine #1.

The associations in there could bring it back to life.  If it's not in the Drive, it's almost certainly in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT - so you can do some more googling to narrow it down.